# APScheduler not executing the python script at 00:00 EST timezone

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

This is my script for cron job.

```
sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone=pytz.timezone('EST'))
sched.add_job(get_data, 'cron', hour='00', minute='00', second='0')
sched.start()
```

I need to make run above job midnight EST timezone
Above job is not working given time,but it is working if we give other than 00 in hour.(hour=01).
My server run in UTC timezone.

Am I missing something here?

Below job working at 01:00 AM EST

```
sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone=pytz.timezone('EST'))
sched.add_job(get_data, 'cron', hour='01', minute='00', second='0')
sched.start()
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug logging to see what's happening? See the Troubleshooting section of the documentation.

Comment: Yes...I already had logging file and it shows next trigger time,but its not happening actually.